# How to Highlight a String in JTextArea By Start and End Position in Java

Tags: java, file, jtextarea

Am having a Text File which is being read in the JTextArea.

I have another program that gives me the start and end position of a String in the Text File.

But when am applying Highlighter in the JTextArea, it is not highlighting what I want.

My Text File Contains:

```
public class John {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    in x;

    }
```

}

I Have a Compiler that gives me the positions where the error occurred in this Format:

```
Code: compiler.err.cant.resolve.location
Kind: ERROR
Line Number: 7
End position: 118
Start Position: 116
```

**strong text**But when I use these positions in my Highlighter code, it does not highlight what I want.
E.G "in" should be highlighter only. Here is what I get as output. I believe that the positions are being changed as they are loaded in the JTextArea.**strong text**

Highlighter Code:

```
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.io.FileReader;

  import javax.swing.*;
  import javax.swing.text.*;

  public class KerlovHighlighter {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Highlighter.HighlightPainter cyanPainter;
private Highlighter.HighlightPainter redPainter;

public KerlovHighlighter() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    try {
        textPane.read(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Antish\\workspace\\Testing\\src\\MyC.java"), null);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to load file " );
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane);
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);//  Highlight some text
    cyanPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.cyan);
    redPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.red);
    try {
        textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(116, 118, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter);

    } catch (BadLocationException ble) {
    }
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            KerlovHighlighter tph = new KerlovHighlighter();
        }
    });
}
```

}

The Output from the code:

```
[1]: http://prntscr.com/tuyqw "Output of Program"
```

The Original Text File:
http://www.mediafire.com/?aiufxocfj0xm21e?

Can someone help.Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that the positions are being changed as they are loaded in the JTextArea.

In Windows the new line string is "\r\n" which is two characters. When you load a text file into a Document the document uses "\n" as the end of line string which is only a single character. So the offset of your highlighting will be off by one for every new line in the file.

Also, we don't have access to your text file so we can't see what your are describing. When you post an SSCCE make sure it is complete. So instead you can do:

```
//textPane.read(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Antish\\workspace\\Testing\\src\\MyC.java"), null);
textPane.read(new FileReader("KerlovHighlighter.java"), null);
```

Now if we execute your code we also have a valid text file to read.

Comment: Then How I will call my TextFile? Myc.Java

Comment: I'm talking about a SSCCE where you use the source file to demonstrate your problem. Once the problem is fixed you use your real file.